# How to get Facebook ID from the Parse User object

Tags: parse-platform

There are Parse user objects created through siging up with Facebook. How can I retrive the Facebook ID from these user objects?

As you can see the Parse User object has Facebook ID in the authData field.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what language/platform you mean but what's wrong with accessing `authData` value of needed Parse User object directly? 
`authData` is a property of User object so you can retreive its value as any other object property.
Like `user[@"authData"][@"facebook"][@"id']` (using Objective C).

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` before accessing `authData`.

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

new Parse.Query(Parse.User).get(objectId).then(function(user) {
    var authData = user.get("authData");
    console.log(authData.facebook.id);
}
```

For more example, you can visit https://loginexample.parseapp.com/ which I built one month ago.